# How to debug OSGi bundles deployed on liberty profile

Tags: websphere-liberty

I'm trying to deploy an Enterprise OSGi application (EBA archive) on Liberty but it fails to start because of bundle resolve problems. I tryed to to use the OSGi console to debut this issue but when I telnet to the console port I can only see the server bundles, not my application bundles. I cannot neither see the bundles from the bundle repository, that I use from my application. Is there a way to have the same feature available in full profile, where a wsadmin shell is provided to debug this kind of problems? If this feature is not available, how to debug OSGi problems?

Answer (score 0):

** Update: Liberty now has an osgiAppConsole-1.0 feature: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/osgi-application-console-feature/ **

Liberty does not have an OSGi console for OSGi applications.  The osgiConsole feature is for the runtime, not for OSGi applications.  The chances are your application is not getting to the point where you would be able to see it in the runtime because it is probably failing resolution during deployment.  You should see a resolution error message which identifies the cause and you can use that to determine what it's looking for (e.g. the package or service) and so you can then investigate what should be providing it.  If you're not getting an error message or need help working out what's missing, I'd recommend posting on the wasdev.net forum.