# osgi - How can I access an OSGi console specific to my EBA file on WebSphere Liberty?

Tags: java, osgi, websphere-liberty

I have deployed an EBA file, consisting of some OSGi bundles, on Websphere Liberty (It is simple example code, and works as expected, no issues there).

How do I access the OSGi console on which the bundles installed within my application would be displayed? I am not referring to the server's OSGi console, which I am able to access, but the console specific to my application.

If there is no such console by default, how do I add a console to my application?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824862/how-to-debug-osgi-bundles-deployed-on-liberty-profile

Comment: That does answer the first question, that there is no such console by default. Is there a way to add a console, then?

Comment: @BX21 No, it is not currently possible.

Comment: @bkail Although, it should be possible for someone to write a bundle that provides a console to the EBA, if it has been added to the file. Is there any such existing implementation that you know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pick up the latest Liberty profile beta you can configure the osgiAppConsole-1.0 feature which will make a web based console available for seeing the content of the OSGi application.

There is a [blog post](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/osgi-application-console-feature/) on how to use this on [wasdev.net](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/)